# using generic method instead of method parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I am using a framework that has this method

```
public static void Initialize<T>() where T : Game;
```

and in sample code you intialize your game like this

```
TargetDevice.Initialize<MyGame>();
```

I am wondering what are benefits of using style of initialization

```
public static void Initialize<T>() where T : Game;
TargetDevice.Initialize<MyGame>();
```

instead of

```
public static void Initialize(Game game);
TargetDevice.Initialize(new MyGame());
```

Is that generic style of initializing method has any name that I can read of? Why should I choose one style instead of another?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't need to pass a `Game` into the first method, it seems odd that you need it for the second. Would a `Type` suffice here?

Comment: It is obvious that in both methods MyGame instance is initialized by TargetDevice. One possible benefit for using the generic method is that the user won't have reference to the actual instance of MyGame. May that is the idea behind this style of generic programming to hide actual instance?

Comment: but with / without an *instance* is unrelated to generics; you could have the generic version with / without an instance, and a non-generic version with / without an instance. That is why I discussed the differences between passing a `Type` vs generic `T`.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the difference between:

```
Foo<T>()
```

and

```
Foo(Type type)
```

then there are merits of both. The latter is much more convenient when using reflecting to load the types (maybe your `Game` types come from plugins?) - generics and reflection don't mix very conveniently.

The generic version is handy when everything is known at compile-time; you can add additional validation via constraints etc, which are enforced by the compiler. It can also be handy if you specifically want to use the `T`, for example to use generic comparisons via `Comparer<T>.Default` or `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` (emphasis: these are just examples) - which accesses many common patterns, while avoiding things like boxing where appropriate.

In your case, since the `T : Game`, boxing isn't an issue (I'm assuming `Game` is a class, not an interface). You could go either way; a `List<Game>` will work almost as well as the *slightly* more specific `List<T>` (where `T : Game`), so it is unlikely to cause problems.

If reflection is involved at all, I'd use the second form, perhaps offering both:

```
void Foo<T>() where T : Game
{
    Foo(typeof(T));
}
void Foo(Type type) {...}
```

Most generic features can be emulated - for example `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` in place of `new T()` - or a cast to a known interface in place of `T : ISomeInterface`. You don't get the use of the "constrained" opcode, but in your case that doesn't apply anyway.